# MPI derived data type

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi

I have an assignment where I need to use the OpenMPI and here I need to create a new type of data to send messages,therefore I googled this and found something.

After following the tutorial I did this:

```
typedef struct {

    int a;
    int b;

}SpecialData;

SpecialData p,q,vector[size];
MPI_Datatype tipSpecial , oldType[2];
int noBlocks[2];
MPI_Aint offsets[2],extent;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

// setup the 7 double fields
offsets[0] = 0 ;
oldType[0] = MPI_DOUBLE;
noBlocks[0] = 7;

//setup the 4 int fields of the struct
MPI_Type_extent(MPI_DOUBLE, &extent);
offsets[1] = 8 * extent;
oldType[1] = MPI_INT;
noBlocks[1] = 4;
MPI_Type_struct(2, noBlocks, offsets, oldType, &tipSpecial);
MPI_Type_commit(&tipSpecial);
///... Some code here where I do things based on the rank.
p.a = 9;
p.b = 9;


MPI_Send(p, 1, tipSpecial, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Recv(q,1, tipSpecial, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

And I get an error at send and receive specially at the first argument.

```
Error:
Main.c: In function ‘main’:
Main.c:125:3: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘MPI_Send’
   MPI_Send(p, 1, tipSpecial, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You should also include what error message you are getting

Comment: You should provide `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` with pointers to the data, i.e. `&p` and `&q`.

Comment: I can't believe it was this thing that cause it all the comotion.Thank you very much.If you can please post your reply @HristoIliev so everybody else can see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` expect pointers to the data buffer as their first argument. Unlike with arrays, in order to obtain the address of a scalar variable, one has to use the reference operator `&`:

```c
 MPI_Send(&p, 1, tipSpecial, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 //       ^
 MPI_Recv(&q, 1, tipSpecial, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
 //       ^
```

Comment: One thing.now when I try to receive something I get an error code 7(Bus Error),is it because the special type object isn't initialised or why?

Comment: With the changes you've introduced, the derived MPI datatype no longer matches the structure.

Comment: Yes.you are right.it was because of that offsets vector.

Comment: The clang compiler now ships with annotations that will catch this type of error.  Normally MPI_Send and MPI_Recv take a void *, but with these annotations clang will consult the datatype argument.